# Cannot access sql manager

Tags: database, sql

I cannot access sql manager on a site which is running EE v 4.0.8
I've checked the file permissions and they look fine.  This is the error message.  Any suggestions of what to check next?

```
View file not found: utilities/sql/manager
ee/EllisLab/ExpressionEngine/Service/View/View.php:331

Stack Trace: Please include when reporting this error
#0 ee/EllisLab/ExpressionEngine/Service/View/View.php(83): EllisLab\ExpressionEngine\Service\View\View->getPath()
#1 ee/legacy/libraries/View.php(39): EllisLab\ExpressionEngine\Service\View\View->render(Array)
#2 ee/legacy/libraries/Cp.php(252): View->render('utilities/sql/m...', Array, false)
#3 ee/EllisLab/ExpressionEngine/Controller/Utilities/Sql.php(117): Cp->render('utilities/sql/m...', Array)
#4 [internal function]: EllisLab\ExpressionEngine\Controller\Utilities\Sql->index()
#5 ee/EllisLab/ExpressionEngine/Core/Core.php(240): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#6 ee/EllisLab/ExpressionEngine/Core/Core.php(109): EllisLab\ExpressionEngine\Core\Core->runController(Array)
#7 ee/EllisLab/ExpressionEngine/Boot/boot.php(146): EllisLab\ExpressionEngine\Core\Core->run(Object(EllisLab\ExpressionEngine\Core\Request))
#8 htdocs/cmssystem.php(147): require_once('...')
#8 htdocs/cmssystem.php(147): require_once('...')
```

Answer (score 0):

One of my system files did not get deployed correctly to the remote server.  Unsurprisingly this was the result!